# how to increase and decrease original number by one each time I press the respective buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I increase and decrease 12 by one each time I press + and -? One more questions is I have other buttons which need to have the same functionality. For those other buttons, do I need to add the same class name and will they work the same? I have been told that I can't have two id which is why I am avoiding using id. Can I achieve this using id? How can I go about that?

```js
const countUp = document.querySelector('.countUp')
const countDown = document.querySelector('.countDown')

countUp.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let count = 0
  count = count + 1
  const counter = document.querySelector('.num')
  counter.innerHTML = count
})

countDown.addEventListener('click', () => {
  count = count - 1
  const counter = document.querySelector('.num')
  counter.innerHTML = count
})
```

```html
<div class="rating">
  <button class="countUp">+</button>
  <span class="num">12</span>
  <button class="countDown">-</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `count` needs to be a global variable. You're setting it back to 0 every time you click on the `countUp` button.

Comment: `let count = 0` is defined inside the click event. The scope of it prevents it from being seen in the other click handler. You probably just want to read the textContent of the span.

Answer (score 2):

Move your declaration of the variable `count` out of the event listener(s) and give it a global scope, and set it to the value of the span on initialization with the `parseInt` function.

```js
const countUp = document.querySelector('.countUp');
const countDown = document.querySelector('.countDown');
const counter=document.querySelector('span.num');
let count = parseInt(document.querySelector('span.num').textContent);

    countUp.addEventListener('click',() => {
        count++;            
        counter.innerHTML = count;
    });

    countDown.addEventListener('click', () => {
        count--;
        counter.innerHTML = count;
    });
```

```html
<div class="rating">
<button class="countUp">+</button>
<span class="num">12</span>
<button class="countDown">-</button>
```